# Create an Identification Question WITH Answer, in Google Forms Using Google Script

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script, google-forms

[image: Feature to be accessed via Google App Scripts]

I've been trying so hard to understand *javascript* as I know only *Python*.

I generate **javascript codes using Python**, to run it on Google Scripts.

I was able to automate creation of any number of Multiple Choice Items by generating codes to be used as script, but I could not figure out how to make a script for Identification Questions (by Identification means answers to questions will be in words). I could make TextItem, but could not "put" the answer to it.

```js
function myFunction() {
var form = FormApp.openById('xxx');
form.setTitle('title')
    .setDescription('description')
    .setIsQuiz(true)
    .setLimitOneResponsePerUser(true)
;
var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
item.setTitle('This is a MultiChoice question.')
    .setChoices([
        item.createChoice('option'),
        item.createChoice('answer', true),
        item.createChoice('option2'),
    ])
    .setPoints(1)
    .setRequired(true)
;
var item = form.addTextItem();
item.setTitle('What is the capital of Japan?')
    .setPoints(1)
    .setRequired(true)
var itemresponse = item.createResponse('Tokyo')
;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal. In order to correctly understand your goal, can you provide the sample output situation you expect as an image?

Comment: I have added an image where a question will have a pre-made answer just like when making a Multiple Choice Item which has a code ".createChoice('this is an option', true)". TextItem does not have that option in the docs but I'm trying to figure out if using javascript alone could solve my problems without referring to the documentation.  I don't know javascript that's why I ask. btw thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the sample image. From your additional information, I proposed 2 sample scripts as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assigning correct answers to text items cannot be achieved programmatically

It is a popular feature request (see https://issuetracker.google.com/117437423 and https://issuetracker.google.com/71637498), but has not been implemented so far.

Unfortunately you cannot do much about it apart from "starring" the issues to give them more visibility and / or changing your questions to multiple choice.

Comment: I found a Rest api documentation for google forms in the link you gave me, I think i should give it a try. Thank you for sharing the link.  I've been "googling" how tos and only just about now i knew because of you, that google has issuetrackers too. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Pattern 1:

When you want to create the Quiz with the choice items using Google Form, I think that you can achieve this using the Google Form service (FormApp). The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample1() {
  const formTitle = "sample1"; // This is a form title.

  // This is an object for creating quizzes.
  const obj = [{ "question": "sample question 1", "answers": ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3"], "correct": ["answer1"], "point": 1 }];

  const form = FormApp.create(formTitle).setIsQuiz(true).setTitle("Sample questions");
  obj.forEach(({ question, answers, correct, point }) => {
    const choice = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    const choices = answers.map(e => choice.createChoice(e, correct.includes(e) ? true : false));
    choice.setTitle(question).setPoints(point).setChoices(choices);
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, a new Google Form is created. And, the Google Form includes a question with the choice items and the answer.

### Pattern 2:

When you want to create the Quiz with the text item using Google Form, I think that you can achieve this using Google Forms API. The flow for using the sample script is as follows.

#### 1. Linking Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project for New IDE.

In order to use Forms API, please link Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project for New IDE, and please enable Forms API at API console. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/Linking-Google-Cloud-Platform-Project-to-Google-Apps-Script-Project-for-New-IDE)

#### 2. Sample script.

```js
function sample2() {
  const formTitle = "sample2"; // This is a form title.

  const form = FormApp.create(formTitle);
  form.setIsQuiz(true).setTitle("Sample question");
  const formId = form.getId();

  // Create request body for Google Forms API.
  const url = `https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/${formId}:batchUpdate`;
  const requests = { requests: [{ createItem: { item: { questionItem: { question: { textQuestion: { paragraph: false }, grading: { correctAnswers: { answers: [{ value: "Sample answer 1" }] } } } }, title: "Sample question 1" }, location: { index: 0 } } }] };

  // Request to Google Forms API.
  const params = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    payload: JSON.stringify(requests),
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

- In this script, please include the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body`.
- When this script is run, a new Google Form is created. And, the Google Form includes a question with a text item and the answer text.
- In this sample script, I proposed to use the batchUpdate method by guessing a case that you want to add the question to the existing Google Form. If you want to use the existing Google Form, please modify `formId`.

#### References:

- [addMultipleChoiceItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addmultiplechoiceitem)
- [Method: forms.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/batchUpdate)
- I thought that these posts might be also useful.

  - [Creating Quizzes in Google Form using Google Forms Service with Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3e131b55c7947ced19a3dd99410367eb)
  - [Creating Quizzes in Google Form using Google Forms API with Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/eebcb2d71eed1aab5decff64287bcc9a)